# Importing data from an Excel file online

Tags: r

I am trying to download an excel file online and read only lines that contains the word "ORD".

```
fileUrl <-("http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur/documents/SRRPT20151211.xls")
x <- getURLContent(fileUrl)
out <- read.table(fileUrl,x )
```

I am using GetUrlContent but receive an error at the early stage of the process:

> Warning messages:
>
> ```
> 1: In read.table(fileUrl, x) : line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls  
> 2: In read.table(fileUrl, x) : line 2 appears to contain embedded nulls  
> 3: In read.table(fileUrl, x) : line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls  
> 4: In read.table(fileUrl, x) : line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls  
> 5: In read.table(fileUrl, x) : line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls  
> 6: In if (!header) rlabp <- FALSE :  
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 7: In if (header) { :  
>    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used  
> 8: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : embedded nul(s) found in input
> ```

The table "out" comes out almost unreadable. Does anyone knows how to read exactly the specific line rather than importing the whole file at the risk of getting the error lines?

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600926/download-a-xls-file-from-url-into-a-dataframe-rcurl) recommends using the [gdata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/index.html) library to download the Excel file from the web and then using `read.xls()` to read it into a data frame.  Something like this:

```
library(gdata)
download.file("http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur/documents/SRRPT20151211.xls", destfile="file.xls")
out <- read.xls("file.xls", header=TRUE, pattern="Some Pattern")
```

The `pattern` flag tells `read.xls()` to ignore everything until the *first* line in which `Some Pattern` appears.  You can change the value to something which allows you to skip the preliminary material before the actual data you want in your data frame.

Comment: HI Tim, thank you very much. I can retrieve the file without any problem. But the issue is that the file is not entirely a dataframe. it contains some descriptive information until a certain row, then there is a dataframe.

Comment: @Pino I updated my answer.  Use `pattern` to skip lines you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution, thank you Tim for putting me in the right direction: 
`library(gdata)`
`DownloadURL <- "http://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur/documents/SRRPT20151211.xls"`
`out <- read.xls(DownloadURL, pattern="ORD", perl = "C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe")`